# Simple JavaScript login form validation

Tags: javascript, html

Just a really simple login and redirect, but the script doesn't fire since I changed the button input type to 'submit' and the onClick event to onSubmit. All is does now is just add the username and password as a string to the url.

```
<form name="loginform">
    <label>User name</label>
    <input type="text" name="usr" placeholder="username"> 
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="pword" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" onSubmit="validateForm();" />
</form>

<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var un = document.loginform.usr.value;
        var pw = document.loginform.pword.value;
        var username = "username"; 
        var password = "password";
        if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
            window.location = "main.html";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
        }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: The script doesn't work. It just adds ?usr=username&pword=password to the url instead of window.location

Comment: Did you type "username" in username field and "password" in password field? Because otherwise it will not pass your `if` statement.

Comment: Just put `onSubmit` handler on the `form` tag instead of `input`.

Comment: The script fires now, when I inputing nothing it goes to the else statement and then prints the ?usr=&pword= in the url but when I enter the correct username and password it still puts ?usr=username&pword=password on the url

Comment: @DanMitchell Check my answer, should do the trick.

Comment: Set the request method to `POST`. `<form name="loginform" method="POST">`.

Comment: all of the comments have helped and the else statement works but if the username and password are correct the page just refreshes.

Comment: @DanMitchell It should "refresh", it means the form is sent. Do you know how forms work?

Comment: @DanMitchell I've just updated my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The `input` tag doesn't have `onsubmit` handler. Instead, you should put your `onsubmit` handler on actual `form` tag, like this: 
   `<form name="loginform" onsubmit="validateForm()" method="post">` 
    Here are some useful links:

   - [JavaScript Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)
   - [Form onsubmit Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp)
2. For the `form` tag you can specify the request method, `GET` or `POST`. By default, the method is `GET`. One of the differences between them is that in case of `GET` method, the parameters are appended to the `URL` (just what you have shown), while in case of `POST` method there are not shown in `URL`.

   You can read more about the differences [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_httpmethods.asp).

**UPDATE:**

You should return the function call and also you can specify the `URL` in `action` attribute of `form` tag. So here is the updated code:

```
<form name="loginform" onSubmit="return validateForm();" action="main.html" method="post">
    <label>User name</label>
    <input type="text" name="usr" placeholder="username"> 
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="pword" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>

<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var un = document.loginform.usr.value;
        var pw = document.loginform.pword.value;
        var username = "username"; 
        var password = "password";
        if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
            return false;
        }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Almost works 100%, it redirects to main.html but the string is still be added to the url.. any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I forget to add method type. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do two things here either move the onSubmit attribute to the form tag, or change the onSubmit event to an onCLick event.

Option 1

```
<form name="loginform" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
```

Option 2

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onClick="return validateForm();" />
```

Comment: @DanMitchell, just make sure `validateForm` always returns `false`;

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function vali() {
var u=document.forms["myform"]["user"].value;
var p=document.forms["myform"]["pwd"].value;
if(u == p) {
alert("Welcome");
window.location="sec.html";
return false;
}
else
{
alert("Please Try again!");
return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<fieldset style="width:35px;">  <legend>Login Here</legend>
<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" required>
<br>
<input type="Password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" required>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return vali()">
</form>
</fieldset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="loginform" onsubmit="validateForm()">
```

instead of putting the onsubmit on the actual input button

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to the form `method="post"`.

Like this:

```
<form name="loginform" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate() {
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        if (username == null || username == "") {
            alert("Please enter the username.");
            return false;
        }
        if (password == null || password == "") {
            alert("Please enter the password.");
            return false;
        }
        alert('Login successful');
        
    } 

  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  <input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate();" />
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I forget to add some explanation. I Will do it in my further answers.